# define a precompiler constant for UI Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need a precompiler constant for UI Testing (to change the way the server mock works). I have tried to set `UITESTS=1` in `Build Settings/Preprocessing/Preprocessing Macros` for the UI testing target. However, when I do:

```
#if UITESTS
  let uitests=true
#else
  let uitests=false
#endif
```

`uitests` is `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go to top bar select Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme ...
Select Test or Run on the left (whichever you are using) and select the Info tab at the top. Make sure Build Configuration is set to `Debug` and not `Release`

Comment: I'm assuming you may have set it to release for upload to iTunes Connect and just forgot to switch it back for debugging purposes.

Comment: @NSGangster everything as it should be, and my scheme has `Optimization Level = None`

Comment: Hmm. are you adding the `UITESTS=1` to release or debug field under `Preprocessing Macros`?

Comment: @NSGangster I am using the correct scheme, and I am setting the macro at the correct scheme

Comment: My only other suggestion is maybe to try adding the same macro to your other targets to see if maybe one of your other targets is running that code. Other than that you seem to be doing it right from my experience with xcode's preprocessing macros